# How to setup two different symfony3/FOSUserBundle on the same DB

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I need to create two different symfony3/FOSUserBundle installation, but they need to share the same database. I tried already but I am probably messing up something with tokens and secret, is there a way to achieve that?

thanks

Comment: Does your application is like this: www/AppSymfony1  and www/AppSymfony2  ?  I usually share such structure for one DB without any problem